# "TypeError: Math.Floor is not a function at load (<anonymous>:4:17) at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on the base for a simple Russian roulette simulator. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>RR</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick=load()>Load</button>
  <button onclick=fire()>trigger</button>
  <script>
    var slot=0;
    var load=function(){
    slot=Math.Floor(Math.random()*6+1);
};
var fire=function(){
  slot=slot-1;
  if(slot===0){
    confirm("BANG!!");
  }else{
    if(slot<0){
      confirm("There is no bullet in this gun.");
    }
  }
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click load I get the error in the title. I know Math.Floor is a function because I've used it before and I looked it up. Did I mess something up in the code? Thanks.

Comment: Js is case sensetive use Math.floor

Comment: @RolandStrake What do you mean?

Comment: He means that `Floor` !== `floor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change...

```
slot=Math.Floor(Math.random()*6+1);
```

to...

```
slot=Math.floor(Math.random()*6+1);
```

As Roland and Sterling pointed out, the floor function starts with a lower case f letter.